# How to timeout a cloudant httprequest?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

What is the way to timeout a cloudant HTTP request if it takes more than some seconds? I am using the [cloudant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cloudant/cloudant/v/3.0.3-SNAPSHOT.12) library. For example, I am having a query that takes some 20 to 30 secs but I want to timeout the HTTP call if the response time is more than 15 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Cloudant client with [requestDefaults](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant/#advanced-configuration) one of the options is `timeout` e.g.

```js
"requestDefaults": { timeout: 15000 }
```

Comment: I think this timeout is for the client connection not for individual HTTP cloudant call. I tested it out but never worked for me.

Comment: I believe it maps to an underlying socket timeout that triggers if the client cannot connect to the host in time or if the socket does not read any data for the given time. It does not behave as a deadline for an HTTP request i.e. if the server is still responding slowly it will not trigger.